# Instruct to execute an unit after completing another unit successfully

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I use cloud-config to install and configure DCOS cluster.

Normally `agentinstall.service` service takes 5 minutes to complete.

Is it possible to instruct to systemd to execute `agentconfigure.service` *only after* `agentinstall.service` completed?

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
    - name: "agentinstall.service"
      command: "start"
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=agent_setup
        After=network.target

        [Service]
        Type=simple
        User=root
        WorkingDirectory=/tmp
        ExecStartPre=/bin/curl -o /tmp/dcos_install.sh  http://bootstapnode-0.dev.myztro.internal:9090/dcos_install.sh
        ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 755 dcos_install.sh
        ExecStart=/bin/bash dcos_install.sh slave

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
    - name: "agentconfigure.service"
      command: "start"
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=agent_config
        After=agentinstall.service

        [Service]
        Type=simple
        User=root
        WorkingDirectory=/opt/mesosphere/etc/
        ExecStartPre=/bin/echo "MESOS_ATTRIBUTES=cluster:uploader" >> /opt/mesosphere/etc/mesos-slave-common
        ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/latest
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart dcos-mesos-slave

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does using the "After" directive not work?

Comment: No , It did not work. I assume it is because After= do not guarantee that  ""agentinstall.service"" has completed.

Comment: Does systemd show the agentinstall service running when it hasn't actually completed the start up?

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a way to get this done with systemd, as I think it is only concerned about starting and running of units. As in, you can use `After=` to force a unit to start only AFTER the specified one has started, or both start in parallel.

`Wants=` will cause the specified units to be started in parallel (if the wanted units are not yet started/active), not what you want.

`Requires=` will, if used in conjunction with `After=` on `agentconfigure.service`, ensure that `agentconfigure.service` is started AFTER `agentinstall.service` is active ("busy"). Now, you could have a loop in `agentconfigure.service` that waits, say max 5 minutes, and regularly checks for `agentinstall.service` to complete before it proceeds with its actual work. The only option I see for this.

EDIT: Another option I think is even better ... `agentinstall.service` starts `agentconfigure.service` when installation succeeds, then exits.

Answer (score 1):

You want to run after the `/bin/bash dcos_install.sh slave` command?

Change the service with that command to `Type=oneshot`.  Also then I don't think you need to use ExecStartPre=, just use ExecStart= for everything.

---

@JdeBP asks me to point out that your `echo` command is attempting to using shell redirection [which will not work](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines).

Comment: Beaten to it.  I was going to suggest the same.  You might want to add to this answer that running `systemctl` within a service is generally a bad idea; that {{ExecStart}} values are not shell script and shell script syntax does not work in them; and that there's probably a need for _two_ oneshots here or maybe some tmpfiles stuff.